# time.sleep() lagging in pygame

Tags: python, windows, pygame, lag

I'm coding a reaction game on pygame for a school project and I'm struggling with lag when I use the time.sleep() in my code. The game is extremely simple, you just have to click as soon as you see the screen changing colors. Everything is working fine but when I try using time.sleep() it becomes laggy and the game loses all its purpose. I was told to use pygame.time.delay() but it does the same thing. (PS : I only need the data from the game so I'm fine with how it looks). Any idea on how I can fix this ?

```
import random
import time
import pygame

pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

START = time.time()
screen.fill((255, 0, 0))
pygame.display.update()
RUN = True
while RUN:
    n = random.randint(3, 9)
    time.sleep(n)
    screen.fill((0, 255, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            RUN = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            END = time.time()
            RUN = False
    pygame.display.update()

var = END - (START+n)
if var < 0:
    print("you clicked too soon")
else:
    print(var, "s")

pygame.quit()
```